# `bind`/`flatMap`/`>>=` over Optional in Dhall

Tags: functional-programming, flatmap, dhall

I needed to `bind`/`flatMap`/`>>=` over an `Optional` in Dhall.

I could not find an implementation for it and came up with my own.

```
let bindOptional
    : ∀(a : Type) → ∀(b : Type) → (a → Optional b) → Optional a → Optional b
    = λ(a : Type) →
      λ(b : Type) →
      λ(f : a → Optional b) →
      λ(o : Optional a) →
        Prelude.Optional.fold a o (Optional b) f (None b)
```

which I then use as follows

```
bindOptional Outer Inner (λ(x : Outer) → x.inner) outer
```

Is there really no such function defined in the `Prelude`? I assume I may have missed it.

Furthermore:

1. is there a more idiomatic way of defining it?
2. is it somehow possible to leverage type inference and make the call shorter? Something like

   ```
   bindOptional _.inner outer -- the compiler infers `Outer` from `outer` and `Inner` from `_.inner`
   ```

I attempted to not give the type parameters but it doesn't seem possible (from my limited knowledge of the language).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of this writing there is not such an operation for `Optional` in the Prelude, although there is no particular reason why it is absent, so you could open a pull request to add it.

The closest mechanism with language support is to use the fact that the `merge` keyword works on `Optional` values, so this would work:

```
merge { Some = λ(_ : Inner) → _.inner, None = None SomeType } outer
```

… although that still requires specifying the `Inner` and `SomeType` types, so it does not leverage type inference.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, PR opened here: https://github.com/dhall-lang/dhall-lang/pull/1076